# Problem about creating component with react

Tags: reactjs, components

I have really little problem ı created a react project then ı create another .jsx for my component but when ı add it the "app.jsx" it's not working ı see 'header' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)'
here is the codes of APP.JSX

```
import './App.css'
import header from './header.jsx';
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

here is the codes HEADER.JSX

````
function header() {
    return (  
<div className='header'>
</div>
    );
}
export default header;```
ı just want to connect app.jsx and header.jsx
````

Comment: Lowercase-starting JSX element names are converted to _strings_ - `React.createElement("header", ...)` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header (semantically, that's also probably what you should be using). So your component _is_ unused.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your component `header` to `Header`, as in React, components starts with a capital letter.
https://pusher.com/blog/troubleshoot-react-errors/#not-starting-component-names-with-a-capital-letter